# SQL ORDER BY FIELD() use array

Tags: php, sql

Hello everyone im just wondering if there is a way for me to pass an array to

```
ORDER BY FIELD()
```

function, so i have something like

```
<?php

$array = (5, 8, 7, 10);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(id,".$array.")";    

?>
```

is this possible? how would i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `implode` to make a comma separated list:

```
<?php

$array = array(5, 8, 7, 10);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(id,".implode( $array, ',' ).")";    

echo( $query );

?>
```

Outputs:

```
 SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(id,5,8,7,10)
```

Comment: Hey Rob! Your answer is perfect! in my case I need to sort the result by the result of another query as follows: SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY FIELD(id, (SELECT orders from table2 where table2.table1_id = table1.id)). Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Sardor - I suggest you ask the question in it's own right.  Comments aren't for follow-ups